# Can i write single method in CodeIgniter Controller to handle both GET and POST login form?

Tags: codeigniter-3

In web application we are using POST and in IPAD we are using GET to submit form details. But I written both GET and POST method in my CodeIgniter Controller. But it's not good because I'm maintaining same code twice in Cotroller?
Current Code:

```
class LoginHandle extends REST_Controller
{
  public function authenticate_post()
  {}
  public function authenticate_post()
  {}
}

Is is possible some thing like following?

class LoginHandle extends REST_Controller<br>
{
   public function authenticate_get_post()
   {}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I expect there aren't many form items to check - you could use (assuming PHP7+) the `??` operator like this:

`$username = $_POST['User'] ?? $_GET['User'];
$password = $_POST['Pass'] ?? $_GET['Pass'];`

For PHP < 7 you can use ...

`$username = !empty($_POST['User']) ? $_POST['User'] : !empty($_GET['User']) ? $_GET['User'] : null;
$password = !empty($_POST['Pass']) ? $_POST['Pass'] : !empty($_GET['Pass']) ? $_GET['Pass'] : null;`

Comment: Thank you for your reply UKUSER, and we are currently using PHP 5.6 version. So I need to have GET and POST in the CodeIgniter Controller (OR) I need to make IPAD developers to use the SAME POST method which is using for the WebApplication

Answer (score 1):

Please, see: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::post_get

```
$this->input->post_get('key')
```